# Is it possible to send args to an afterScenario function?

Tags: karate

I saw in the doc that it it possible to define a function in the background part and execute it after each scenario.
see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/hooks/hooks.feature

But i need to send args to this function and don't find any solutions...

In the doc:

```
* configure afterScenario = 
"""
function(){
  var info = karate.info; 
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.scenarioName);
  karate.call('after-scenario.feature', { caller: info.featureFileName });
}
"""
```

What i would like to do:

utils/js/afterFunc.js:

```
function fn(args){
  karate.log('after', args.msg);
}
```

myTest.feature:

```
* configure afterScenario = read('classpath:utils/js/afterFunc.js') {msg: 'Hello !'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` function will read the `afterFunc.js` file, but it ignores the `{msg: 'Hello !'}` parameter.

[Scripts can call other scripts](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files) but you don't want to call the script immediately, do you?
You want to create a function reference and assign that reference to the `afterScenario` configuration.

But that's not enough. You want to curry the function - [what is currying?](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339)

AFAIK this is not support by `read` directly.

There is a workaround.
You can read the javascript file and create a function that calls your `after-scenario-function` with a parameter of your choice.

```
  Background:
    * def fn = read('classpath:after-scenario-with-params.js')
    * configure afterScenario =
    """
      function() {
        fn(karate.info, 'hello world');
      }
    """
```

The `after-scenario-with-params.js` contains the following js function:

```
function fn(info, someParameter) {
    karate.log('called after scenario:', info.scenarioName);
    karate.log('some parameter: ' + someParameter);
}
```

That's it.

I committed a  [complete running example](https://github.com/peterquiel/karate-experiment/commit/118ea47350be8fa00bc37916e70152303d732ed1) to my karate sandbox repository. The repo is gradle and groovy based. I hope it helps.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you for your answer ! FYI the naming of the function is important because if you call another .js file in one of the scenarios with a function also named "fn" in it, this workaround doesn't works anymore...